# Inprog Action Already In Progress caused by jquery.blur()

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, events, angularjs-directive

I have `input field`:

```
<input type="text" id="myId" ns-validate="" class="someClass" ng-model="Date" ng-
focus="focus($event, 'Parameters')" ng-blur="blur($event)" tabindex="-1">
```

focus event is bind to this method:

```
scope.focus = function (e, names) {
            scope.dateSet = false;
            $(e.currentTarget).blur();
            $(e.currentTarget).prop('readonly', true).addClass('focus');
        };
```

if I comment out `blur()` no error occures but it is needed to make readonly work on IE.

May it be caused by this that blur event is bind to this method:

```
scope.blur = function (e) {
            $(e.currentTarget).prop('readonly', false).removeClass('focus');
        };
```

If yes why this is working in IE but fails in Chrome?

As suggested in comments I tried to create a directive:

```
angular.module('xxx').directive('blurChecker', function () {
return function (scope, element, attributes) {
        scope.$watch(attributes.blurChecker, function(){
            element[0].blur();
    })
};
});
```

added to html

```
blurChecker='true'
```

with no effects. Any ideas?

Comment: HTML `ng-blur="blur($element)"`  JS: `scope.blur = function (ele) {
            ele.prop('readonly', false).removeClass('focus');
        };`

Comment: sry not working. object doesn't have prop

Comment: Then do the same thing using directive..you will get a better controller on DOM..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always make DOM manipulation from directive. That will give better control on DOM which you want to manipulate.

Use link function inside your directive. because you also need to update scope variable. And then bind blur & focus event to element inside your link function.
As you are passing the "Parameter" string on focus. you can do the same by mentioning attribute inside your element like `parameter="Parameters"`

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="myId" ns-validate="" class="someClass" ng-model="Date" 
blur-checker parameter="Parameters" tabindex="-1">
```

**Directive**

```
angular.module('tpmobile').directive('blurChecker', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var parameterName = attrs.parameter; //I don't know what it does here, but you can get parameter name here
            element.on('blur', function(event) {
                element.prop('readonly', false).removeClass('focus');
            });
            element.on('focus', function(e) {
                scope.dateSet = false;
                element.blur();
                element.prop('readonly', true).addClass('focus');
            })
        }
    }
});
```

Hope this could help you. Thanks.